# Visual Studio 2012 code formatting on CSHTML lowercases generic model types

Tags: razor, visual-studio-2012, code-formatting

When formatting code a Razor cshtml file in Visual Studio 2012 (with Ctrl + K + D) if model is a generic type, VS makes it all lowercase. For example:

```
@model IEnumerable<Content>
```

converts to (consider all lower case *content*):

```
@model IEnumerable<content>
```

after formatting. This cause the code not to compile. Is this a bug or I'm missing something? How it can be fixed?

Comment: Bug submitted http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/828. Just upvote it.

Comment: This still happens with VS 2013: While the setting "HTML -> Formatting -> As entered" will preserve the casing the source will still get indented unneccesarilly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This issue is from Visual Studio 2012 not recognizing it as razor code and treating it as regular HTML. I believe this is a bug with VS 2012 and will hopefully get fixed soon. As a temporary fix, you can do this:

1. Goto TOOLS -> OPTIONS
2. Select Text Editor -> HTML -> Formatting
3. Set the Client Tag drop down to "As entered"

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

If this is a new project in VS 2012, you need to add this line of code in your `<appSettings>`section of your main `web.config`file:

```
<add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0"/>
```

If this was a pre-existing project you probably already have that key in your `web.config`. Make sure it is for version `1.0.0.0` and not 2.X or 1.2.X

Also ensure that your project reference to `System.Web.WebPages` is for version `1.0.0.0` and not `2.0.0.0`

**After you make these changes you have to then close and re-open Visual Studio 2012!**

Comment: The last answer I gave was more of a crutch for the real problem.

Comment: What if you are using WebPages 2.0.0.0 ? MVC4 ?

Comment: My other solution below should do the trick. You have to set the formatting of Client tags to as entered. Just remember to keep you parameters lowercase to conform with CSS standards since Ctrl + K + D will no longer automatically make them lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me with **Visual Studio Professional 2012, ASP.NET MVC 5 and  Microsoft.System.Web.WebPages 3.0**:

```
<add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
```

**But this solution did not work immediately**

At first, Chris Haddox's solution regarding `webpages:Version`:

```
<add key="webpages:Version" value="1.0.0.0"/>
```

did not work for me, I already had this key and it was set to 1.0.0.0.

But since I am using **Visual Studio Professional 2012, ASP.NET MVC 5 and  Microsoft.System.Web.WebPages 3.0**...

This issue showed me that my Web.Config `webpages:Version` was set to `1.0.0.0`, I changed it to `3.0.0.0` because I read in another article that might be correct for Microsoft.System.Web.WebPages 3.0 and I still had the formatting bug for a little while.

I continued to make edits to my .cshtml file. Then, all of the sudden formatting started working correctly. Maybe from building, but I do not think that I did do a build, but can't be sure, and I know that I did not restart Visual Studio 2012.